# Anaconda python and Zsh issue on macOS Sierra

Tags: terminal, osx, zsh, python

I have Anaconda installed on my Macbook Pro with macOS Sierra with Zsh as a shell and Oh My Zsh.

GUI is working fine, but I have problem with commands in terminal.

When I want so start jupyter, I get an error:

```
zsh: command not found: jupyter
```

Answer (score 2):

This was sort of a while ago now, but I figure all you need to do is add `jupyter` to your path. The path on my system is `/opt/conda/bin/jupyter`, and if yours is the same you should be able to run the following:

```
echo 'export PATH="/opt/conda/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

And your `PATH` will be updated to include `jupyter` (and other conda-installed executables). If your path to `conda/bin` is different you'll have to update the `export` accordingly.

**NOTE:** Keep in mind that the above `$PATH` may be different when dealing with different releases of macOS. For example on macOS 10.14 Mojave with `zsh`:

```
$ cat ~/.zshrc
...
# Anaconda
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin/:$PATH"
...
```